# Auto redraw window possible in SDL-2?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Here is a minimal SDL-1.2 text output example (stripped from the lazyfoo tutorial for ttf):

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <string>

SDL_Surface *message = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Event event;
TTF_Font *font = NULL;
SDL_Color color = { 255, 255, 255 };

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Test message", NULL );
    font = TTF_OpenFont( "anyttffont.ttf", 20 );
    message = TTF_RenderText_Solid(
        font, "My test message", color );

    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = 0;
    offset.y = 150;
    SDL_BlitSurface( message, NULL, screen, &offset );
    SDL_Flip( screen );

    bool quit = false;
    while( quit == false )
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                quit = true;

    SDL_FreeSurface( message );
    TTF_CloseFont( font );
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting executable redraws the window automatically after re-exposing it (after minimizing or obscuring).

Is it possible to do something like this in SDL-2?

I tried the equivalent tutorial from lazyfoo for SDL-2, but this has code to constantly re-render the text in the event loop. It stops re-drawing when the render code is moved in front of the loop. I also tried rewriting it using the window surface directly and then using `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(gWindow);`, but this behaves the same way.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. The lazyfoo tutorial explains that static text should be rendered into a texture, which can then be drawn efficiently in the loop. http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/16_true_type_fonts/index.php

Comment: @SMeyer: Yes, may be my problem with SDL-2. I don't understand why I need to render something in a loop, when it does not change a bit. It's just my feeling to move unnecessary code out of the loop. SDL1.2 was easier for me.

Comment: Ah, I see. Potentially, you could prepare the renderer before the loop (e.g. with `SDL_RenderClear`, `SDL_RenderCopy`, ...), and then only call `SDL_RenderPresent` inside the loop.